# How to reload kivy string

Tags: python, kivy

The following code:

1. loads two kv strings.
2. starts a thead on which the third kv string is loaded.

This works only if you comment out '@mainthread'. Isn't GUI update suppose to be on the mainthread?

```
import kivy
import threading
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock,mainthread
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kivy.require('1.9.0')

KV1='''
<Example>:
  Label:
    text:'one'
'''

KV2='''
<Example>:
  Label:
    text:'two'
'''

KV3='''
<Example>:
  Label:
    text:'three'
'''

#@mainthread
def update():
    Builder.load_string(KV3)

class Example(BoxLayout):
      pass

class MyApp(App):
      def build(self):
          return Example()

Builder.load_string(KV1)
Builder.load_string(KV2)

vThread=threading.Thread(target=update)
vThread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   MyApp().run()
```

Comment: When you load a `kv` string with an element like `<Example>:`, it is creating a rule about how an instance of `Example` should be built. Any instance of `Example` that is created after the `kv` loading will follow the current rule. In your case, loading three versions of the `<Example>:` rule simply results in a rule that contains three `Labels`, then the `return Example()` creates an `Example` instance with three `Labels`. If you use `@mainthread`, you are just delaying the loading of `KV3`, so that when `return Example()` is run, the current rule only has two `Labels`.

Comment: Since `Builder.load_string()` does not directly update the GUI, it does not need to be run on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for wonderful explanation. I really needed to understand this since I am new to both Python and Kivy. You are right in saying that mainthread delays the loading of KV3. I removed mainthread which caused the third label to be displayed but when I called time.sleep(1) before loading KV3, the third label didn't display which proved your point. Thank you. But my question now is how to update GUI after loading KV3?

Comment: Trying to update a GUI by loading more `kv` files is very odd. Once you have executed `return Example()` no amount of `Builder.load_string()` will have any effect on the GUI. By analogy, that is like trying to change a pie into a cake by changing the recipe after the baking is complete. Typically, the GUI is modified by using methods like `add_widget()` or `remove_widget()` (which must be run on the main thread).

Comment: @JohnAnderson, I want to click 'solved' but there are only comments.